# How to get channel fields in {exp:structure:siblings}

Tags: structure

How can I access channel fields in {exp:structure:siblings}? I've tried the following code and title and url get output fine but {page_listing_icon} doesn't get parsed.

```
{exp:structure:siblings}
   {prev}
      <a href="{url}" title="{title}">{page_listing_icon} {title}</a>
   {/prev}
   {next}
      <a href="{url}" title="{title}">{page_listing_icon} {title}</a>
   {/next}
{/exp:structure:siblings}
```

Comment: guess you need structure entries for that

Comment: I've been using structure entries but I couldn't find a way to get the next/prev sibling like how {exp:structure:siblings} does.

Comment: if you pass the entry_id's in fixeed order maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [Stash](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash) to help with this:

```
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:structure:siblings}
        {stash:prev_entry_id}{prev}{entry_id}{/prev}{/stash:prev_entry_id}
        {stash:next_entry_id}{next}{entry_id}{/next}{/stash:next_entry_id}
    {/exp:structure:siblings}
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:parse}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="pages"
        fixed_order="{stash:prev_entry_id}|{stash:next_entry_id}"
        dynamic="no"
    }
        <a href="{page_url}" title="{title}">{page_listing_icon} {title}</a>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob that works a treat. I also added `class="{if '{entry_id}'=='{stash:prev_entry_id}'}previous-entry{if:else}next-entry{/if}"` so I can float them left/right using a css class.